# What counts as an "active" user?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

The billing dashboard appears to indicate that you only pay for "active" users:

[image]

Who counts as an "active" user?

Comment: 'active' should be 'activated' implying the opposite is deactivated and not inactive

Answer (score 20):

Active users are defined as any Stack Overflow for Teams users that have not been deactivated.

In the admin dashboard, under "members" you click "manage", you can see all active/inactive users and deactivate any user that you would like.

Comment: FWIW, using the word "active" here makes it sound a bit like "we don't change you for users that don't actively participate".

Comment: good point. we actually changed it from simply "users" for the same reason - we were concerned that people thought "inactive" users might be included in the total user count. Do you have any thoughts on how you'd clarify it?

Comment: I think it very unlikely anyone would expect to be charged for deactivated users. If it were me, I'd go with "users".

Comment: I would suggest *enabled* and *disabled* instead of *active* and *inactive* for this purpose.  The first is associated with configuration, the second with monitoring (although somewhat open to interpretation, because it can be confused with *activated* and *deactivated*).

Comment: @ChanceHeath Change wording from 'Active' to 'Activated' in both the users column and the renew total column. Would solve this issue entirely

Comment: @user1114 please don't use the term "disabled users" you know what that could strike in people xD

Comment: @KyleBurkett: But then people might (e.g., I *would*) think that it takes an explicit activation for users to be included in this count. According to my current understanding, this is not the case. I suggest the monstrous but unambiguous “non-deactivated”.

Comment: This seems to be a case of "if they can't figure it out, too bad for them." I would leave it alone.